# Command Prompt Closes Too Fast After Running A Service

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a problem with a service.  I have an installed application that runs as a service; when I start that service, a command prompt opens and immediately closes.  The program isn't executing properly and I need to see the error output but the command prompt closes too quickly.  Is there a way to force the window to remain open?  Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 5):

Put a PAUSE in the batchfile.

```
MyApp.exe
PAUSE
```

That's all

Answer (score 1):

Services cannot create console windows, they run in their own session with their own "desktop".  Given that you see one, I'd have to guess that you didn't actually create a service.  What happened when you tried to install it with InstallUtil.exe?

This [MSDN Library page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cktt23yw.aspx) has recommendations to debug a service's OnStart() method.

Answer (score 0):

Since a service doesn't allow for user-interaction, could you instead redirect your message to stderr or a file? Or post something to the Event Viewer?

Answer (score 0):

If the service doesn't keep it's own log file, there might be an error visible in the Event Log on that machine.  You can open the EventViewer from the Control Panel / Administrative Tools section.